# Nuxt i18n causing Higher TBT(Total Blocking Time). Need a way to solve it please

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js

I made an app with up to 17 languages, this is causing an issue with TBT(Total Blocking Time) [Which causing a lower score on pageSpeed].

nuxt.config

```
modules: [
   "@nuxtjs/axios",
      [
     "nuxt-i18n",
     {
       detectBrowserLanguage: {
         useCookie: true,
         alwaysRedirect: true
       }
     }
   ]
 ],

i18n: {
   seo: true,
   strategy: "prefix_except_default",
   locales: [
     {
       code: "es",
       iso: "es",
       file: "es.js",
       name: "Español",
     },
     {
       code: "fr",
       iso: "fr-FR",
       file: "fr.js",
       name: "Français"
     },
     {
       code: "cn",
       iso: "zh-CN",
       file: "cn.js",
       name: "中文(简体)"
     },
     {
       code: "de",
       iso: "de-DEU",
       file: "de.js",
       name: "Deutsch"
     },
     {
       code: "br",
       iso: "pt-BR",
       file: "br.js",
       name: "Português"
     },
     {
       code: "id",
       iso: "id",
       file: "id.js",
       name: "Indonesia"
     },
     {
       code: "in",
       iso: "hi",
       file: "in.js",
       name: "हिन्दी"
     },
     {
       code: "it",
       iso: "it-IT",
       file: "it.js",
       name: "Italiano"
     },
     {
       code: "jp",
       iso: "ja-JP",
       file: "jp.js",
       name: "日本語"
     },

     {
       code: "en",
       iso: "en",
       file: "en.js",
       name: "English",
       isCatchallLocale: true,
     }
   ],
   baseUrl: "https://www.apkdojo.com",
   lazy: true,
   langDir: "lang/",
   defaultLocale: "en",
   vueI18n: {
     fallbackLocale: "en"
   }
 },
```

> In this code here, I didn't paste all the locales.

Any solution to this, which can help me to reduce TBT?
Need a faster method to use i18n. Need a way to reduce execution time?

Comment: Did you try to lazy load the translations? https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/lazy-load-translations

Comment: Yes lazy option set to true.